# Qt 4: How to insert QAction in menu of mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt, menu, widget

My problem is to get the QAction of custom widget from the outside and insert in menu of mainwindow. There is QActionWidget but it inserts custom widget in menu.

```
 class QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT Photo_list: public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Photo_list(QWidget* parent = 0);
  ~Photo_list();
  int count();
  QString returnImagePath(const int i);
  void sendSignalImageLoaded();

public slots:
  void addImagePath();
  void deleteImagePath();

signals:
  void imageLoaded(int count);

  //private:
public:
  Ui::Photo_list *m_photo_list_ui;
  QStringList m_image_path_list;
};



 class Ui_Photo_list
{
public:
    QAction *addImageAction;
    QAction *deleteImageAction;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QListWidget *listWidget;

    void setupUi(QWidget *Photo_list)
    {
        if (Photo_list->objectName().isEmpty())
            Photo_list->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("Photo_list"));
        Photo_list->resize(274, 210);
        addImageAction = new QAction(Photo_list);
        addImageAction->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("addImageAction"));
        deleteImageAction = new QAction(Photo_list);
        deleteImageAction->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("deleteImageAction"));
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(Photo_list);
        gridLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gridLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout"));
        gridLayout->setHorizontalSpacing(0);
        listWidget = new QListWidget(Photo_list);
        listWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("listWidget"));
        listWidget->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideMiddle);
        listWidget->setMovement(QListView::Static);
        listWidget->setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);
        listWidget->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);

        gridLayout->addWidget(listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1);


        retranslateUi(Photo_list);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Photo_list);
    } ...
```

How to add QAction *addImageAction in ( * )? (see comment below)

```
 class Ui_Cpdfa
{
public:
    QAction *createPdfAction;
    QWidget *centralwidget;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout_2;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QLineEdit *pdfPathLineEdit;
    QPushButton *findPdfPathButton;
    Photo_list *photo_list;
    QToolBar *toolBar;
    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QMenu *menu;
    QMenu *menu_2;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *Cpdfa)
    {
        if (Cpdfa->objectName().isEmpty())
            Cpdfa->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("Cpdfa"));
        Cpdfa->resize(386, 303);
        createPdfAction = new QAction(Cpdfa);
        createPdfAction->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("createPdfAction"));
        centralwidget = new QWidget(Cpdfa);
        centralwidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralwidget"));
        gridLayout_2 = new QGridLayout(centralwidget);
        gridLayout_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"));
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout();
        gridLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout"));
        pdfPathLineEdit = new QLineEdit(centralwidget);
        pdfPathLineEdit->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("pdfPathLineEdit"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(pdfPathLineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        findPdfPathButton = new QPushButton(centralwidget);
        findPdfPathButton->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("findPdfPathButton"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(findPdfPathButton, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        photo_list = new Photo_list(centralwidget);
        photo_list->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("photo_list"));


        gridLayout->addWidget(photo_list, 1, 0, 1, 2);


        gridLayout_2->addLayout(gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        Cpdfa->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);
        toolBar = new QToolBar(Cpdfa);
        toolBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("toolBar"));
        Cpdfa->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, toolBar);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(Cpdfa);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuBar"));
        menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 386, 21));
        menu = new QMenu(menuBar);
        menu->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menu"));
        menu_2 = new QMenu(menuBar);
        menu_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menu_2"));
        Cpdfa->setMenuBar(menuBar);

        toolBar->addAction(createPdfAction); //!!(*)
        toolBar->addSeparator();
        menuBar->addAction(menu->menuAction());
        menuBar->addAction(menu_2->menuAction());
        menu->addSeparator();
        menu_2->addAction(createPdfAction); //!!(*)

        retranslateUi(Cpdfa);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Cpdfa);
    } // setupUi
```

Comment: I have custom widget photo_list. There are actions QAction *addImageAction; QAction *deleteImageAction in  class Ui_Photo_list.

Comment: I try to add these actions of my widget in another program. Photo_list *photo_list is declared in this program.How to add action of custom widget in this program to QToolBar and QMenuBar.For example toolBar->addAction(createPdfAction); (QAction *createPdfAction is defined in program, but QAction *addImageAction is not there, it's widget action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using Qt creator and designing forms separately with the form editor.

Your problem is acutally that you want the class `A`(a "larger" widget which comprises the subobjects) to access members in the namespace of its subobject `B`(your photo_list widget).

To do this,

1. Move the inclusion `"ui_B.h"` from `B.cpp` to `B.h`
2. Inside `B.h` make the private memeber `Ui::B *ui;` public (or you can have `A` and `B` become friends)
3. After including `"B.h"` and having a subobject pointer `*B`, you can call `B->ui->actionXXX` in `A` to access all memebers of `B`, since `B->ui` points to the namespace that includes all memebers created from `B.ui` file (which turn out to be inside `"ui_B.h"`)